# Symfony2 SensioGeneratorBundle generate forms fields by type

Tags: forms, symfony, generator, date-format, custom-fields

I'm customizing how Symfony2 SensioGeneratorBundle generates forms, initially bundle adds all fields of the entity to the form, but without specifying the type of field, I want the date fields type are automatically generated with a specific format default and so not modify the forms. The original code of the SensioGeneratorBundle is as follows

```
//vendor\sensio\generator-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Resources\skeleton\form\FormType.php.twig
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    {%- for field  in fields %}
        ->add('{{ field }}')
    {%- endfor %}

    ;
}
```

I would like to know the type of field to add it and if such date be adding settings to display on a single line, something like this

```
$builder->add('date_created', 'date', array(
'widget' => 'single_text',
'format' => 'd/m/Y'));
```

Comment: Are you looking for this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864883/sonata-admin-date-choice-wrapping

Comment: I've created my own Crud generator for a different purpose. You can extend the existing bundle and replace the templates. I haven't looked at the code so I'm not sure if you can get the models metadata at that point.