# Sonata Admin date choice wrapping

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm (obviously) new to Symfony/Sonata, I have a problem where Sonata admin is wrapping my date choice onto 3 lines.

php:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($statsForm)
    ->add('startDate', 'date', array('years' => range(2015, date('Y')), 'format' => 'y-M-d', 'widget' => 'choice'))
    ->add('endDate', 'date', array('years' => range(2015, date('Y')), 'format' => 'y-M-d', 'widget' => 'choice'))
    ->getForm();
```

twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<div class="col-md-3">
{{ form_widget(form) }}
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

screen:
[image: 1]

Comment: Which is your version of sonata and symfony ?

Comment: Someone has already answer a similar question here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443558/sonata-admin-bundle-datepicker-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you have to choose the `sonata_type_date_picker` type in your form:

```
$datagridMapper
        ->add('startDate', 'sonata_type_date_picker')
        ->add('endDate', 'sonata_type_date_picker')
    ;
```

The documentation reference:

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html

Comment: thank you sir!  followed instructions at https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html and it is working perfectly.